# Angular's FormControl with Pipe

Tags: angular

I'm trying to coerce the value of an `<input>` using a pipe AS WELL AS see the coerced value in a `<paragraph>`.  However, I cannot seem to get it to work.  I've tried many iterations and scoured the web, but the other solutions do not quite fit, are too long to implement (which doesn't seem right), or work but are not dynamic (I have to click in another control to see the change).

An example pipe I have is PipeAdd10.  It will take a number and add 10 to it.  Again, this is just an example pipe.

Here's what I've tried.  Again, the input(s) are in a form already, and I need myModField to reflect the piped value:

```
<input type="text" #inp>
<p #inpMod>{{ inp.value | add10 }}</p>
<input type="hidden" formControlName="myModField" [value]="inpMod.innerHTML">
```

The solution above doesn't work.  Here's another one I've tried:

```
<input type="text" #inp>
<input type="text" formControlName="myModField" [value]="inp.value | add10" readonly>
```

This, too, doesn't work as the FormControl is not updated, and I want DYNAMIC changes; that is, I want the readonly field to change as soon as digit is entered into the first input control.

Suggestions and advice are always appreciated.  Thank you, all.

Trecius

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Like whats the end goal because what you are asking is weird.

Comment: I'm just trying to coerce -- or change -- an input value, which is bound to a FormControl, as well as display the coerced value on the page.  I have a input control that the user enters a value, but I want the value attached to the FormControl to be the MODIFIED value, which comes from the pipe.  I also want to display the modified value on the page.  In continuing my example above, if I input a value of 23, I want the FormControl value to be bound to 33 (23 + 10) because it goes through my 'add10' pipe.  Additionally, I want to show 33 in a paragraph element on the page.

Comment: `oninput="this.value = (this.value | add10)"`

Answer (score 0):

You could update the value onBlur with setValue. You shouldnt do it while the user is typing. So here what it could look like.
html:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="myModField" (blur)="add10()" (change)="onChange($event)">
```

ts:

```
add10(): void {
    const value = this.form.controls['myModField'].value;
    this.form.controls['myModField'].setValue(value + 10);
}

tempValue = 0;
onChange(value: any): void {
    this.tempValue = Number(value) + 10;
}
```

You can use tempValue somehwere else in the html. I cant remember if `onChange` gets the last entered value or the complete string so it might be a bit different

Comment: While that will probably work, can it be displayed to the user in ANOTHER paragraph or readonly input element at the same time that the user is typing?  Thank you.

Comment: @TreciusVeil You could but it needs to be a different variable otherwise you will end up with an infinite loop